# Where to buy polystyrene coving in the US (idaho)

Tags: drywall

I'm trying to find a source for [polystyrene coving](https://www.diy.com/departments/pro-cove-classic-c-profile-polystyrene-coving-l-3m-t-12mm-pack-of-6/932663_BQ.prd) but I have had absolutely no luck finding it state-side. Anyone have any experience in a method of making coving or sourcing this material?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The key is to not assume that they're all made of polystyrene.

https://www.certainteed.com/drywall/products/certainteed-decorative-moulding/

Comment: According to the website there are a number of distributors in my area. I'll have to take some measurements and see if they can order it in but this is even better than what I was hoping for. Appreciate you sharing your knowledge.